# Memory issue in my android

Tags: android

I have written code to display records dynamically. The problem is that my app crashes after I have changed the orientation of the device a few times. Could it be a memory issue? If yes, could you please provide the steps on how to free up the memory and stop memory leak.

```
    LinearLayout lh1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lLibrary);
    lh1.removeAllViews();
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i < libraryListFromDB2.size(); i++) {
        UserLibrary library = libraryListFromDB2.get(i);
        LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageLayout_layout, null);

        TextView tvType = (TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.tvlibraryType);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.tvlibraryName);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.tvlibraryDate);


        tvName.setText("text");

        String expiryDate = getExpirationDate();
        String expiresDisplayDate = "";
        if(expiryDate != null && expiryDate.length() > 0){
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy",Locale.getDefault());
            DateFormat outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd",Locale.getDefault());
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = df.parse(expiryDate);
                calendar.setTime(date);
                libraryExpiryMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                expiresDisplayDate = outputformat.format(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) lv.findViewById(R.id.libraryThumbNails);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(clickMeListenerLibrary);

        String imageURL = library.getThumbnail();
        if(imageURL != null) {
            String displayImagePathSmall = imageURL;
            String displayImagePathSmallfileName = displayImagePathSmall.substring(displayImagePathSmall.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            if(displayImagePathSmallfileName != null && displayImagePathSmallfileName != "") {
                File imgFile = new File(getActivity().getBaseContext().getFilesDir(), displayImagePathSmallfileName);
                    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }    
        lh1.addView(lv);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace as well?

Comment: I am not seeing any error in the logcat it just crashes.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the code that is loading the bitmaps into imageviews? If the images are not being cleared up correctly and you are loading a lot of them, it could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Please paste error also

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge your application crashes due to memory leak.So you can overcome by make  using of this [library](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) for loading your images from server. And have a look at this [document](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html) too.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that when ever the above code is executed the memory in the device is increasing(Task manager). If I switch between apps or changing the orientaion.

Comment: Indeed,If you are not loading the images smoothly it crashes, you may try ViewHolder()